# Can't see menu buttons on python using tkinter class

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't get `mButton1` to display a menu showing `Orlando` and below it `Cancun`. 
I'm trying to build a widget button that when clicked will show in a menu 2 cities, as when booking a flight.

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()

        self.label1 = Label(frame, text = "Destination:")
        self.label2 = Label(frame, text = "Adults:")
        self.label3 = Label(frame, text = "Child:")
        self.label1.grid(row=0)
        self.label2.grid(row=1)
        self.label3.grid(row=2)

        self.entry2 = Entry(frame)
        self.entry3 = Entry(frame)
        self.entry2.grid(row=1,column = 1)
        self.entry3.grid(row=2,column = 1)

        self.button = Checkbutton(frame, text="Roundtrip:")
        self.button.grid(row=3)

        **self.mButton1 = Menubutton(frame, text = "Destinations", relief=RAISED)
        self.mButton1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.mButton1.menu = Menu(frame, tearoff = 0 )
        self.mButton1["menu"] =self.mButton1.menu
        self.orlandoVar = IntVar()
        self.cancunVar = IntVar()
        self.mButton1.menu.add_checkbutton (label= "Orlando", variable = self.orlandoVar)
        self.mButton1.menu.add_checkbutton (label = "Cancun", variable = self.cancunVar)
        self.mButton1.grid**

root = Tk()
```

Comment: "__init__" is on it's own line, indented properly, (and has two underlines on each side which you probably have but it shows as bold because it's not formatted as code) http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html#d0e11720

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu must be a child of the menubutton

```
self.mButton1.menu = Menu(self.mButton1, ...)
```

Comment: Yes!! I had just figured it out too lol. Thank you so much though!

Answer (score 0):

I create buttons by using:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
btn=Button()
btn.pack()
btn["text"]= #enter your own text here {orlando}
def click():
    #put what you want your button to do here
btn["command"]=click
```

I hope this info has helped, reply if you need more info.